# Node API: Paramterization in routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to build up an api for my website. However I kind of struggle with the route params.
I have two routes for now:

```
const route1 = require('./routes/route1')
const route2 = require('./routes/route2')
app.use('/route', route1)
app.use('/route/:id/details', route2);
```

The first route works perfectly fine. Within the first route, I check for the ID param as well as I do gets like

Code in route1

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
...
})
```

I can easily check for the ID as a paramter in my query.

I wanted to make a 2nd path, so that I can call for the details of one object.
However its not working as expected. 
Code in route2:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
})
```

My parameters are always empty in this path. (I already checked that it can get called)

Comment: So your issue is in the route /route/:id/details you can't access the id on the query params or that route isn't ever hit?

Comment: Route2 gets hit but I won't have my ID available.

Comment: so if you try http://localhost:3000/route/10/details then your console.log(req.params.id) is undefined?

Comment: which version of expressjs are you using?

Comment: Yea exactly. I'm running express on 4.17.1

Comment: can you try this:

app.use('/route/:id/details', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you use router add this to the top of that file:

i.e. in router.js

```
const router = require('express').Router({mergeParams: true});
```

notice the {mergeParams: true} you need this since you're nesting your routes in another file.  If you left your routes all in on file, i.e.

```
app.use('/route/:id/details', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params);// works fine
});
```

then you wouldn't need the mergeParams true flag.